# How can I add new line to a dynamic text in Flash using AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How can I add new line to a dynamic text in Flash using AS3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the problem is I am reading the text from XML file, example:

```
<filename>02.jpg</filename>
<str1>Well-trained legs \n polycarbonate blends</str1>
<str2>Secure his ski-glide</str2>
```

"\n" and "
" is not working so that the only solution that I found is passing the my text to this small function

```
function textMan(str:String):String{
return str.replace("\\n", "\n");}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use "\n" for a newline (or maybe <br /> if the textfield is htmltext). Make sure it is set to multiline though.

Answer (score 3):

if you want the textfield to automatically go to multiple lines set wordWrap to true and define the tf width

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a newline at the top of an HTML textfield, and the source text is in an XML file, try this:

```
<![CDATA[<br/>
TextField text with a newline at the top (normally discarded by Flash)]]>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
trace ('Hisham'+String.fromCharCode(13)+'Shaaban');
```